# Compile a blocks src directory and main index.js entry file and output to different build dirs?

Tags: block-editor, scripts

I have one entry file containing global libs and scripts for the site at `/src/index.js` and a directory in my theme root at `namespace-blocks` containing dirs for each block with `block.json`'s and `index.js`'s in each directory. Can I use wp-scripts without extending it with a webpack config to compile both into separate directories?

Using `npm i concurrently` i'm able to do this and just output each build to separate build directories in my theme root like `build` and `build-blocks` but this isn't ideal.

Currently my NPM scripts look like this:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start:custom-directories\" \"npm run start:custom\"",
    "start:custom-directories": "wp-scripts start --webpack-copy-php --webpack-src-dir=diesel-blocks --output-path=build-blocks",
    "start:custom": "wp-scripts start src/index.js --output-path=build"
  },
```